# Create a daily portfolio tracker in Google Sheet, with importxml

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to track the daily stock value and date of some stocks in a Google Sheet. Currently, the data capture code works well, but it replaces all values with new ones everytime a change happens. 
In A2, i have a cell based on IMPORTXML that takes the date from Morningstar, and on B2, based on SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(importxml(CONCATENATE... that takes the daily value from FT.

My script code now is show next:

```
function saveData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet2")

  var current_date = sheet.getRange('Tracker!A2').getValues();
  var current_value = sheet.getRange('Tracker!B2').getValues();

  sheet.appendrow([current_date, current_value]);
```

Tracker is the name of the page. Running code tells me that I cannot getRange from null. What is the problem, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, 3 sheet names, which are "sheet1", "sheet2" and "Tracker", are used. `ss` and `sheet` are the sheet object of "sheet1" and "sheet2", respectively. And, `current_date` and `current_value` are retrieved from "A2" and "B2" on the sheet of "Tracker", respectively.

  - In this situation, I think that the reason of the error of `Running code tells me that I cannot getRange from null.` is that the sheet of the sheet name of "sheet2" might NOT be included in your Spreadsheet.
  - But, in your script, `sheet.appendrow([current_date, current_value]);` is used. So you want to put the values to the sheet of "sheet2" or other sheet? About this, I couldn't understand from your question.
- When you want to use `appendrow`, please modify to `appendRow`.
- In your script, the 2 dimensional array retrieved by `getValues()` is used as the value of `[current_date, current_value]`. In this case, even when `appendrow` is modified to `appendRow`, the value like `[Ljava.lang.Object;@###` is put to the cell.
- If you want to retrieve the values from the cells of "A2" and "B2" on the sheet "Tracker" and want to append the retrieved values to a sheet, you can use `Tracker!A2:B2` as the range.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please set the destination sheet name to `sheetName`.

```
function saveData() {
  var sheetName = "###";  // Please set the destination sheet name.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var value = ss.getRange('Tracker!A2:B2').getValues();
  ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).appendRow(value[0]);
}
```

#### References:

- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation)
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#appendrowrowcontents)